# curl_multi_exec shows different runs

Tags: php, curl, php-curl, curl-multi

I am using curl_multi_exec() for just 5 url.
Now i have this strange issue. When i run my code on xampp , it works perfect. i can see $running value initialized with 5 and then keeps decreasing.
.
But, when i tried it on other localhost(on arm architecture), $running gets initialized with 0.
so my curl_multi_exec() never returns any response.

Here is the code snippet :

```
do {
curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($running );
echo "</pre>";
} while($running > 0);
```

Here is my entire code:

```
    $nodes = array( 'https://www.example.com',
            'https://www.example2.com',
            'https://www.example3.com',
            'https://www.example4.com',
            'https://www.example5.com'
            );
    $node_count = count($nodes);

    $curl_arr = array();
    $master = curl_multi_init();
    for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
    {
    $url =$nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);  
    }

    do {
   curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
   echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($running );
   echo "</pre>";
   } while($running > 0);


   for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
   {
    $results = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i]);
    var_dump($results);
    }
```

I googled a few things and got to know curl ssl might be an issue. So, i installed another localhost(on ARM) with openssl and curl ssl enabled.
Now i have two different localhost(both for ARM) with SSL enabled, this snippet works fine on one localhost and doesn't work on the other one.

And somehow i need that "other one" because it has lot more features.

Someone please guide what might be the issue with this $running initialization?

Any help is appreciated :)

Tried this also, but no success

```
                                    <?php

            // echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3'/>" ;

                include_once ("simple_html_dom.php");
                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

            function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
                $string = ' ' . $string;
                $ini = strpos($string, $start);
                if ($ini == 0) return '';
                $ini += strlen($start);
                $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
                return substr($string, $ini, $len);
            }

            function multi_thread_curl($url_array, $number_threads) {
             $curl_array = array_chunk($url_array, $number_threads, $preserve_keys = true);
            //Iterate through each batch of urls.
            foreach($curl_array as $threads) {
                //Create your cURL resources.
                foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {
                ${'ch' . $key} = curl_init();
                curl_setopt(${'ch' . $key}, CURLOPT_URL, $value);
                curl_setopt(${'ch' . $key}, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt(${'ch' . $key}, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt(${'ch' . $key}, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

                }
                //Create the multiple cURL handler.
                $mh = curl_multi_init();

                //Add the handles.
                foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

                curl_multi_add_handle($mh, ${'ch' . $key});

                }

                $active = null;

                //execute the handles.
                do {

                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

                } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

                while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
                    echo $active;

                    if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
                        do {

                            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

                        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
                    }
                }
                //Get your data and close the handles.
                foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {
                $results[$key] = curl_multi_getcontent(${'ch' . $key});
                curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, ${'ch' . $key});
                }
                //Close the multi handle exec.
                curl_multi_close($mh);
            }
            return $results;
            }
            $nodes = array( 'https://www.example1.com',
                            'https://www.example2.com',
                            'https://www.example3.com',
                            'https://www.example4.com',
                            'https://www.example5.com',
                            );
            $node_count = count($nodes);
            echo "results: ";
            $number_threads = 5;
            $results = multi_thread_curl($nodes, $number_threads);
            print_r($results);
            echo 'done';


            ?>
```

Issue Here is : `$active is always 5`. Forever Loop :(

Comment: please post your curl code.  And putting a multi exec curl function inside a while loop probably is not a good practice

Comment: @Joseph_J  curl_multi_exec always works inside while to keep track of current running handles. You can visit : [curl_multi_exec php.net official](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) to have a look :)

Comment: My apologies, you are right.  For some reason I was thinking it was a function you had written that contained the curl_multi_exec.

Comment: @Joseph_J That's OK :) . Any Help or comment is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a multi-thread-curl function that I put together using examples from PHP.net.  I have used this function to get large amounts of URL's.  It is capable of really speeding things up.  I have had great success with it.

You could even expand on it and add a parameter for your curl options.

```
function multi_thread_curl($url_array, $number_threads) {


$curl_array = array_chunk($url_array, $number_threads, $preserve_keys = true);

    //Iterate through each batch of urls.
    foreach($curl_array as $threads) {

        //Create your cURL resources.
        foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

        ${'ch' . $key} = curl_init();

        curl_setopt(${'ch' . $key}, CURLOPT_URL, $value);
        curl_setopt(${'ch' . $key}, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt(${'ch' . $key}, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt(${'ch' . $key}, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

        }


        //Create the multiple cURL handler.
        $mh = curl_multi_init();

        //Add the handles.
        foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, ${'ch' . $key});

        }

        $active = null;

        //execute the handles.
        do {

        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

        while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {

            if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
                do {

                    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

                } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            }

        }

        //Get your data and close the handles.
        foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

        $results[$key] = curl_multi_getcontent(${'ch' . $key});

        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, ${'ch' . $key});

        }

        //Close the multi handle exec.
        curl_multi_close($mh);

    //Limits to one group of threads.
    //break;

    }


    return $results;



}

$urls = array(

  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki'

);


$results = multi_thread_curl($urls, 1);

print_r($results);
```