# cURL fast way to stream images

Tags: php, api, curl

I know that cURL's performance is quite fast however since the files I'm streaming is on a different server, it took 4-5 minutes to complete.

Is there any way to do 100 requests in 10-15 seconds? I have tried multi-process of cURL and the effect is still the same even file_get_contents().

Thank you

```
<?php 
require_once('FileMaker.php');

use \setasign\Fpdi;
use \setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\StreamReader;
require_once('FPDi/vendor/setasign/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('FPDi/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once('FPDi/src/PdfParser/StreamReader.php');

$pdf = new Fpdi\Fpdi();

$fm = new FileMaker('database sample', 'location sample', 'username sample', 
'password sample');

$connected = $fm->getLayout('Accessioning | Desktop  | Form');
if (FileMaker::isError($connected)) :
 // echo '<script> alert("NOT CONNECTED"); </script>';   
endif;
 //echo '<script> alert("CONNECTED"); </script>';   


$record_gathered = $fm->getRecordByID("Accessioning | Desktop  | Form", "18226");
$related_records = $record_gathered->getRelatedSet('Library | Accession Catalog Items');
$result_gathered_information = array();
$result = array();


if (!FileMaker::iserror ($related_records)) {
 foreach($related_records as $related_record){
  @$counter = $counter + 1;

    if ($counter <= 3){
         $fetchURL = 'http://sampleURL/SuperContainer/RawData/Library/Catalog/Items/'.  $related_record->getField('Library | Accession Catalog Items::recno') . '/?a=1';

         $result_gathered_information[] =  $fetchURL;
    }

  }
}

foreach ($result_gathered_information as $detectedinfo){

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $detectedinfo);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $result[] = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

}

foreach ($result as $file) {

 $pageCount  = $pdf->setSourceFile(StreamReader::createByString($file));

    for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++) {
    // import a page
    $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    // get the size of the imported page
    $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

    // add a page with the same orientation and size
    $pdf->AddPage($size['orientation'], $size);

    // use the imported page
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
    $pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
   }
  }
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Have you tried curl_multi_exec.  Try this example.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126688/curl-multi-exec-shows-different-runs/50127353#50127353

Comment: @Joseph_J: I tried also curl_multi_exec before and it goes also the same thing.